# Spring oauth2 Local and external token generation

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am planning to secure my REST server with external Identity provider(WSo2) or local spring ouath token generator. Token generation mode(Eternal/Internal) will be made configurable. I took the example listed below and modified the CORSFilter class to verify token with External provider(WSO2).                  I am not sure how to skip the local token generation and access my resource server here. I guess the authorization and Resource server needs to be separate module to achieve what I need.I am completely new to spring ouath so not sure if this is the right way. I tried all over the internet to find better example but not able to get one. Any pointers/examples will be helpful.

URL(example): http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Read the keygen mode if it is External validation do this else skip all this so that local token is generated.

        LOG.info("###token is"+ req.getHeader("Authorization"));
        String token = req.getHeader("Authorization");

        TokenValidator obj = new TokenValidator(token);//This class validates the Access token with WSO2
        boolean tokenStatus = obj.gettokenStatus();
        if(tokenStatus){
             res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            chain.doFilter(req, res);

        }else{
            LOG.info("token validation is not scuesfull");
            throw new SecurityException();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/                                                                                                    In the above example the authorization and the resource server are bundled together. I need a example where both is running as separate entity so that I can integrate with external auth provider or use the Internal spring authorization.

Comment: i think you will add token enhancer for this scenario